# Use javascript variables in c# in cshtml files

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

How can i use javascript values in c# in cshtml.

```
@Html.Confirm(@Mui.confirm_delete, yesText: Mui.Yes, noText: Mui.No)
```

Can i use javascript variables as arguments and how?